# How do I visualise the variables in OpenSTM32? Is it like in Open STM Studio?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, eclipse

I am programming a standard STM32F407 board under Linux. And I'm looking for a way to visualize the variables on a graph in an OpenSTM32 environment.

How do I visualize the variables in OpenSTM32. Is it like in Open STM Studio?

[image]

Comment: stackoverflow.com might be a better place to ask this question since you're asking about _how to program something_ verses something _hardware related_.

Comment: This http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread269 says that live variable update hasn't been implemented yet. One work-around, (or hack) is to write an app that does a telnet into OpenOcd to read (or write) a data structure at a fixed memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on the same thing. Here how I did it (not the GUI part).

You can use OpenOCD and gdb to debug/view variables.

Start an OpenOCD server:

```
sudo openocd -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/board/st_nucleo_f4.cfg -c "init"
```

I assume you are working with a STM32F4DISCOVERY (STM32F407VG), so you should use `stm32f4discovery.cfg` config file.

Now start gdb in another terminal:

```
sudo gdb
```

Provide your object file (.elf/.axf) to gdb which contains debug info, symbols and etc. If you are using Keil uVision (MDK-ARM), you can find the .axf file under `myProject/MDK-ARM/myProject/` folder. If you are using GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain, you should compile your program as a debug program, so compiler generates an .elf file under `../Build/` folder.

In gdb console:

```
file ~/myProject/Build/myProgram.axf
```

Now you can monitor your variables by name with gdb since you provided the object file.

Connect to OpenOCD server from gdb:

```
target remote localhost:3333
```

You can now see your variables from gdb with `p myVar1`, the type of the variable with `ptype myVar1` and the address of the variable with `info address myVar1` commands:

```
p myVar1
```

Here is a simple script which prints the desired variables every 1 second.
You can run the script with `gdb --batch --command=script.gdb`:

```
shell sudo openocd -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/board/st_nucleo_f4.cfg -c "init" &> /dev/null &

file b/BUILD/NUCLEO_F446RE/GCC_ARM/b.elf

target remote localhost:3333

#monitor reset run

display myVar1
display myVar2

while(1)
    display
    shell sleep 1s
```

Code on STM32:

```
uint32_t myVar1 = 0;
uint32_t myVar2 = 0;

int main(void){
    while(1){
        myVar1 +=1;
        myVar2 +=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not run openocd or gdb as root.  Use a udev rule or whatever to grant access by your regular user to the debug adapter.  Also you probably want the a target version of gdb, not the host one.